# Why does my lognormal curve not appear? (R)

Tags: r, statistics

I am attempting to to plot a histogram with a lognormal curve over it. For some reason the curve is not appearing in the plot. My matrix of data has NAs in it so I tried to remove them in the function by omission.
This is the data I'm using right now.

```
c(767.25, 759.5, 770.5, 783.5, 773.25, NA, NA, NA, 793.25, 797.25, 
803.5, 824.5, NA, NA, 835.25, 838.25, 856.5, 846.25, 825.75, 
NA, NA, 840.75, 835.75, 863, 859, 853.75, NA, NA, 858.75, 874.25, 
886, 862.75, 867, NA, NA, 872, 840.25, 837, 850.75, 822.25, NA, 
NA, NA, 762.25, 763, 747.25, 776.5, NA, NA, 782.5)
```

```
Lognormal_Conversion <- function(z){
  
  #Colors for graph and line
  #user1 <- tolower(readline(prompt = "Colors for graph and line (a,b): "))
  #ColorListParsed <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(user1, ',')[[1]], as.character))
  #ColorBars <- toString(ColorListParsed[1])
  #ColorLine <- toString(ColorListParsed[2])
  
  #removing the NAs
  z2 <- na.omit(z)
  
  #Moments
  u <- mean(z2)
  std <- sd(z2)
  lu <- exp(u + (std^2)/2)
  lsd <- sqrt( (exp(std^2) - 1) * exp(2*u + std^2) )
  lskew <- (exp(std^2) +2) * sqrt( (exp(std^2) - 1) )
  lkurt <-  exp(4*std^2) + 2 * exp(3 * std^2) + 3 * exp(2 * std^2) - 6
  
  #Making lognormal line
  Logline <- dlnorm(x = z2, meanlog = lu, sdlog = lsd)
  
  #Getting variable name for plot title
  VarName <- deparse(substitute(z))
  
  #Making the graph
  zseq <- seq(min(z2), max(z2))
  hist(z2, main = paste("Histogram of ", VarName))
  lines(z2, Logline, lty = 1, col = "pink", lwd = 2) #Adding lognormal line
  
  
}
```

I then get the following message:

```
Warning message:
In dlnorm(z2, meanlog = lu, sdlog = lsd) : NaNs produced
```

Comment: Try with `hist(..., freq=FALSE)` or other modifications to the range of the y-axis to ensure the range of the y-axis enables both your histogram and density curve to be "on" the plot

Comment: I do not think that warning is coming from the NA's. I think it's coming from negative numbers being present in the data. Have you examined your results? Have you looked for negative numbers.

Comment: Your data consist of a single variable, `z2`. Give us about 50 values using `dput(head(z2), 50)` and pasting the results into your question as a code block. You should just delete the image file, it is not helpful. You can answer @IRTFM's question with `summary(z2)`.

Comment: I realize in ```lu <- exp(u + (std^2)/2)``` that is too large a number